Sharing Google Colab Notebook with Kaggle Dataset
What’s the best way of sharing a colab notebook that requires a kaggle dataset? Should I download the Kaggle data to Google drive then share the notebook and the drive file? Or should I use the Kaggle API within the notebook?
